# Android - Information leakage flaw OutputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream

I have developed an application in the Cordova Framework, and I have added a camera plugin for capture functionality.

I am getting an Information Leakage flaw in the code below i think i need to initialize , using veracode to scan APK.
Do i need to initialize OutputStream?

```
OutputStream os = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
try {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, this.mQuality, os);
    os.close();
} finally {
    if (os != null) {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three lines of non-leaking code as a try-with-resources statement:

```
try (OutputStream os = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)) {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, this.mQuality, os);
}
```

Comment: its saying try-with-resources statement is not supported in this api level

Comment: i am able to use try with resource by using latest java version and minsdk 19

Comment: i tried try resource but i am still getting warning - information exposure through sent data